# Don't use BuildContext across sync gaps

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a button in my Flutter app.

```
onPressed: () async {
  try {
    final newUser = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
    if (newUser.user != null) {
       await Future.delayed(Duration.zero);
       Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(ChatScreen.id);
    }
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
},
```

The IDE reports "Don't use BuildContext across sync gaps.".
What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**When doing asynchronous tasks during widget's synchronous operations, you must check the widget is still available.**

For your case, right before the Navigator line, add this line

```
if (!mounted) return;
```

By doing so you check the current Widget is mounted and usable. If the Widget is being rebuilt or destroyed, checking if it's mounted will return false.

**If it returns true it means the Widget is ready and you can use async / sync tasks almost everywhere.**